# How to match a string in jquery

Tags: jquery, select

I am using a select dropdown. I used ids in value and in option tag content i used a string. Now i want to match a string with jQuery

here is the code:

```
<select id="options-1" class=" product3090 options" name="products[3090][options][]">
  <option value="">Select an option</option>
  <option value="1">Personal Use - Digital</option>
  <option value="2">Small Organisational License</option>
  <option value="4">Medium Organisational License</option>
  <option value="5">Large Organisational License</option>
  <option value="6">University/College License</option>
  <option value="7">Personal Use - DVD</option>
</select>
```

When i change a drop down in jQuery it alerts me all values correctly. Now i want to match "Organisational" word that if this match it alerts me "yes" else "No"

Here is my jQuery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).change( function () {
    var theValue = $("#options-1").text();

    //alert(theValue);

    if(theValue.indexOf("Organisational") > -1){
        alert("Yes");
    }
    else{
        alert("No");
    }

});
</script>
```

When i select any of them it always alert me yes. What can i do any idea

Comment: Why `$(document).change( function () {`?

Comment: It should be `$("#options-1").change` not `$(document).change`. Check this http://jsfiddle.net/PN8Re/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
var theValue = $("#options-1 option:selected").text();
```

Get the selected option.

---

You can attach change handler to the select element

```
$('#options-1').change(function () {
    var theValue = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
    if (theValue.indexOf("Organisational") > -1) {
        alert("Yes");
    } else {
        alert("No");
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanx alot @Tushar Gupta Thumbs up

Comment: Tushar can you tell me why i use this > -1, because i copied this from another tutorial and i don't get this

Comment: @Nadeem  `.indexOf()` returns `-1` if the value to search for never occurs . So if it greater than `-1` than value is present

Comment: @Nadeem Welcome. Read [indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)

Answer (score 2):

use `$("#options-1 option:selected").text();` to get selected option text.

`$("#options-1").text()` returns text off all the option that are there in `select`.

also change `$(document).change` to `$('#options-1').change`:

```
 $('#options-1').change( function () {
 var theValue = $("#options-1 option:selected").text();
 if(theValue.indexOf("Organisational") > -1){
    alert("Yes");
 }
else{
    alert("No");
 }});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4yacQ/)**

Answer (score 1):

`$("#options-1").text()` will give you text content of every option inside `select`.

In your case, you need to get text of the selected option only, so you can do:

```
var theValue = $("#options-1").find('option:selected').text();
```

instead of:

```
var theValue = $("#options-1").text();
```

Also, you need to attach change event to the `select` element instead of `document`:

```
$("#options-1").change( function () {
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/YwCv4/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

```
 $("#options-1").change( function () {

     var theValue = $("option:selected").text();

    alert(theValue);

    if(theValue.indexOf("Organisational") > -1){
        alert("Yes");
    }
    else{
        alert("No");
    }

});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U2jd3/)